# How to combine two dynamic selectors to a new selector?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs, ngrx-selectors

I have the following selector

```
static orderFilteredByStatus(status: string){
    return createSelector([OrderState], (state: OrderStateModel) => {...}
}
```

Now I have another selector in a different state.

```
static status(name: string)
    return createSelector([DashboardState.settings], (dashboardSettings: DashboardSetting[]) => {...}
}
```

Now I want to combine both selectors to create a new selector so that the value of the selector `status` is passed to the selector `ordersFilteredByStatus`. Something like that:

```
@Selector([OrderState.orderFilteredByStatus(DashboardState.status("fixedName")])
static ordersDashboard(orders: Order[]){...}
```

Is that possible? I know that you could combine the selectors via `switchMap()` but I want a new selector combining both if that is possible. The parameter `name` is fixed

Answer (score 2):

You can compose selectors

@Selector([MyStateOne.getAll, MyStateTwo.getAll])
static getCombinedData()

You can see an live example of NGXS implementation of Mark WhitField (Project Lead of NGXS) here in this GH repo.

https://github.com/markwhitfeld/ngxs-diner

Orders.queries.ts has an example of this @Select() composition